# How to read arbitrary XML into generic object in Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have a whole bunch of XML sources I need to read.  They don't have schemas and, though they are all well formed and contain nothing but strings, they also don't really share a structure; some are only one level deep, others multiple, some contain repeating blocks/records while others contain a bunch of different blocks describing different aspects of a particular record.

Previously, I used `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser` with a custom handler to take the XML input and use it to set the fields of a custom object, which was fine when I only had one thing to read, with a fixed structure and number of records that I knew in advance and no sub keys or sub sub keys.  In PHP, I would read the whole thing into a multidimensional associate array, but Java doesn't seem to have an exact equivalent.

I presume I need some kind of `Map` or `List` but I don't understand what sort or how to use it.  Is there a standard Android-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `List` of `Maps` to simulate multidimensional Array in PHP.

```
List<Map<String, String>> multidimArray = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

// This is the first element in Array
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
multidimArray.add(map);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question about parsing XML?

Comment: @Code-Guru, Haven't you read the question? `In PHP, I would read the whole thing into a multidimensional associate array, but Java doesn't seem to have an exact equivalent.

I presume I need some kind of Map or List but I don't understand what sort or how to use it. Is there a standard Android-y way of doing this?`

Comment: What if some of the elements in the array, as well as straightforward key/value pairs, also contain elements that need to be key/arrays too?

Comment: @vestofwarlock, that makes it hard to maintain later on. I think your best move it to choose an XML library. There are few out there which I think are worth trying: [`Simple XML`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), [`XMLPull`](http://www.bearcave.com/software/java/xml/xmlpull.html), [`XMLPullParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different more-or-less standard XML object models: you should use one of them.  This article [Working with XML on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/) gives a summary of some options for Android.  DOM is the document object model that is most widely-available.  Its API is kind of horrible to work with directly, but you will be able to query against it using `XPath`, which is a convenient syntax for accessing different nodes in an XML tree (see [javax.xml.xpath | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html)).